# get scroll position of safari

Tags: javascript, java, macos, safari

G'day

I'm trying to reliably get the scroll position of the Safari Y axis, on an iMac.

Using this below is nowhere near reliable, and I'd like to use Javascript, but I'm no Java programmer.

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
                                    tell window 1
                                        set scrollPosBeforeScroll to scrollPos
                                        key code 121
                                        try
                                            set scrollPosKeep to scrollPos
                                            set scrollPos to value of scroll bar 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 as text

The benefit of using Applescript to get the scroll position is it returns a value from 0 to 1, 1 when the window has finished scrolling. But it often fails.

From what I can find on Java, it keeps on increasing the y value depending on the number of pages in the view, could be 8800 for example. Not good. I need to know when the scrolling is finished (i.e. reached 1)

Can anyone tell me how to do what I need in JavaScript please. I've fruitlessly searched.

Comment: Are you talking about Javascript or Java?

Comment: I think I want javascript.

Comment: There's an Applescript command 'do javascript' etc.